# Object State Restore on transaction rollback

Tags: object, transactions

I would like to restore all non transactional objects on transaction roll back. Ex:: if a List object holds two objects before transaction starts and assume after transaction two more objects are added to it.On transaction rollback the List object defined should restore its state ie; should contain only first two objects.I am using Spring Declarative Transaction management.

Thanks for any suggestions, in advance...

Comment: The clue is in your question - "non transactional objects". If they're non-transactional, they *can't* be rolled back, by definition.

Comment: No magic exists.  You must create your own.  The objects must understand transactions and must store state prior to a transaction beginning.  It also applies to anything they reference.  Welcome to the rabbit hole.

Comment: Can u say how can that be done:: store state prior to transaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Software Transactional Memory (STM) may be a good solution for your problem.   It is primarily meant for handling concurrent scenarios but would work just as well for single threaded applications that need rollback capability.

You are probably not going to be able to use Spring Declarative Transaction management but the STM model is easy to use.

Akka-STM (http://doc.akka.io/stm-java) is a good choice especially if you need JTA support.   There is also Multiverse (http://multiverse.codehaus.org/overview.html) and other Java implementations.

Comment: +1 for STM. Check out Multiverse which gives you STM on top of JVM. Akka uses Multiverse under the hoods. JVSTM and Duece are others which are out there.